# glGetAttribLocation returns large and unusable value

Tags: opengl

It seems my `glGetAttribLocation` is returning a value of `4294967295` and I'm not sure why. I've seen a lot of people with it returning `-1` but not so many with my problem. The problem is that it returns a value greater than `GL_MAX_VERTEX_ATTRIBS` meaning I can't use `glEnableVertexAttribArray` to send my normals to the shader. Would anyone know what this function would return such a high value?

Comment: Are you sure it's not `4294967295` instead? Which would be `-1`, printed as an unsigned.

Comment: You'd be right, I forgot to copy the last digit over, thanks for the help aha

Comment: "but not so many with my problem"... Beucause most of recognize -1 casted to unsigned int...

Answer (score 3):

The value 4294967295 is the largest value that can be represented by an **unsigned** 32-bit number. If you convert it to hex, it's 0xFFFFFFFF.

`glGetAttribLocation()` returns a value of type `GLint`, which is a **signed** 32-bit value. If you interpret the 0xFFFFFFFF value you got as signed value, it is in fact -1. [*]

So you did get a return value of -1, which means that the attribute was not found. The common reasons for this are:

1. An attribute with the given name does not appear in the shader code.
2. The attribute with the given name was optimized away because it is not used.
3. The program you passed in is not valid.
4. The program you passed in was not successfully linked.

The surprises for getting this return value are often caused by reason 2.

[*] At least that's true on machines that represent signed values in a 2's complement form, which is the case for almost anything these days.