# Why glGetAttribLocation returns same value for two different attribute?

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-3

i'm a beginner in OpenGL, and i write a vertex shader and do other things like compiling shader.

Vertex shader:

```
in vec4 vPosition;
in vec4 vColor;

out vec4 Color;

void main(void){
    gl_Position = vPosition;
    Color = vColor;
}
```

After i write this code in C++:

```
GLuint PositionID = glGetAttribLocation(SProgram, "vPosition");
GLuint ColorID = glGetAttribLocation(SProgram, "vColor");

cout << "vPosition location: " << PositionID << endl << "vColor location: " << ColorID << endl;
```

And result was pretty interesting, two same locations:

```
vPosition location: 4294967295
vColor location: 4294967295
```

What is why of that?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29170900/glgetattriblocation-returns-large-and-unusable-value. Not sure if this is close enough to be marked as a duplicate, but it's basically the same answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually the return type of [`glGetAttribLocation`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glGetAttribLocation.xhtml) is not `GLuint` but `GLint` (which is signed).

So `4294967295` it's indeed `-1` which means that a problem occurred somewhere. Causes could be many:

- program is invalid or incorrectly linked
- attribute is not used
- attribute name is invalid

It's hard to tell the cause since we can't guess your code but the problem is somewhere else.